# 2d array check the rows value with an if statement

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to loop through the rows of a 2d array to check the if the row matches the property of a method. How can I use an if to just check the row? This is my code

```
 public void recordWhiplashPoints(ConnectionToClient client, int vote){


    int[][] votecount = new int[game.getPlayers().length][0];


    outside:
    if(game.getRecordedAnswers() <= game.getPlayers().length){
    for (int i = 0; i < game.getPlayers().length; i++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < votecount.length; q++) {
            if(votecount[q] == vote){
                //do stuff
            }

        }
      } 
    }
}
```

So where votecount[row] is. Can I compare that with the property vote some how?

Comment: Sure, you already are. But it's an empty array, so I'm not sure what you're really after.

Comment: You don't use your `i`, but you do use `col` without defining it

Comment: Is it not initialized at the top of the method? If getplayers().length has 3 spots would it not create a 2d array with 3 rows with a column each set to null? I haven't really worked with 2d arrays before

Comment: Fixed to [q] but I am still getting "bad operand types for binary operator == int[] to int

Comment: `votecount` is a 2D array. When you call `votecount[index]`, you call another array. The problem is that you try to compare it with `int vote`

Comment: So is there a quick way to compare the votecount[index] with the integer I am passing in? Could I just pass int vote as a 2d array instead with only the same amount of rows as votecount?

Comment: can't you just do `votecount[i][0] == vote`? you also don't need second for loop as well as you basically have 2D array (votecount) have with 1 column

Answer (score 1):

So for two dimensional arrays, which is basically just an array of arrays, you get a member array using something like `votecount[i]`, and you get a member of that array with `votecount[i][q]`.  I think the following is the code you want:

```
int[][] votecount = new int[game.getPlayers().length][0];

outside:
if(game.getRecordedAnswers() <= game.getPlayers().length){
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // note that we need to compare against the array votecount[i]
    for (int q = 0; q < votecount[i].length; q++) {
        // here we access the actual element votecount[i][q]
        if(votecount[i][q] == vote){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but one way to do so would be to use for-each loops

```
public void recordWhiplashPoints(ConnectionToClient client, int vote){


int[][] votecount = new int[game.getPlayers().length][0];


outside:
if(game.getRecordedAnswers() <= game.getPlayers().length){
for (int[] i : votecount) {
    for (int q : i) {
        if(q == vote){
            //do stuff
        }

    }
  } 
}
```

}

Essentially the first for-each loop goes through each array the 2d votecount array, and then the second for-each loop goes through each of those 1D arrays. If you have any questions just ask.

However, I don't understand how your second if statement will be true, as you never change votecount from anything other that the default, which is a 2D array filled with 0's.